# Solution to non-linear first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, nonlinear-system

I have the following differential equation -

$s(1-s)t = f'(t)(f(t)-st)$

Initial condition: $f(0) = 0.$

I solved it and got the solution as -

$$ f(t) = \sqrt{2 c_1+s^2-2 (s-1) s \ln (t)}+s $$

But the answer given is -

$f(t) = k(s)t,$

where

$$k(s) = \frac{s+ \sqrt{4s - 3s^2}}{2}.$$

If anyone can provide me some hint on how to proceed and reach the specified answer, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Sorry, yes! I have edited the question.

Comment: Yes, it is this equation only.

Comment: Yes, it is this equation only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given, $f(t)=k(s)t,$ where
$$k(s)=\frac{s+\sqrt{4s-3s^2}}{2},$$
is correct, as you can verify by differentiating and plugging into the DE. It is evident by inspection that $k(s)t$ satisfies the IC.

As for finding the solution, guess-and-check proves to be the best method. You can see by inspection that some constant (that is, some quantity constant with respect to $t$) times $t$ might be able to solve the DE, and it certainly satisfies the IC. So, posit $f(t)=k(s)t,$ plug it into the DE, and solve for $k(s):$
\begin{align*}
s(1-s)t&=k(s)(k(s)t-st)\\
s(1-s)&=k(s)(k(s)-s)\quad\text{for}\; t\not=0.
\end{align*}
Now solve for $k(s),$ (might need the quadratic formula) and you're finished.

Comment: Thank you. But my question is how could I have reached this solution if the answer wouldn't have been provided?

Comment: The form of the equation suggests a linear function in $t$. It requires imagination to see that, but there's no other way to solve this equation that I know of.